# istream::operator>> or istream::get

Tags: c++, c++11

I was testing a block of code from the C++PL book and found the next piece of code (I didn't want to feel like I was copypasting it from the book to my IDE so I , at least, changed the variable names):

```
istream& operator>> (istream& is, MyContact& mc)
{
    char ch1, ch2;
    string ContactName{""};
    if (is>>ch1 && is>>ch2 && ch1=='{' && ch2=='"')
    {
        while(is>>ch1 && ch1 != '"')
            ContactName+=ch1;

        if (is>>ch1 && ch1==',')
        {
            int ContactAge=0;
            if (is>>ContactAge>>ch1 && ch1=='}')
            {
                mc={ContactName, ContactAge};        
                return is;
            }
        }
    }

    is.setstate(ios_base::failbit);
    return is;
}
```

According to [this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/?kw=istream%3A%3Aget) istream::get "Extracts a single character from the stream"

And according to [this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/) istream::operator>> "Extracts as many characters as possible from the stream"

Out of curiosity, I replaced

```
if (is>>ch1 && is>>ch2 && ch1=='{' && ch2=='"')
```

with

```
if (is.get(ch1) && is.get(ch2) && ch1=='{' && ch2=='"')
```

And it worked. No compilation errors and the program apparently did what it was supposed to do, now my question is:

**Why is the operator `>>` used in the context where we extract a single char, when an `is.get()` would be equally functional?**

Comment: Well it is 3 less characters to type.

Comment: This would be one less test `if (is >> ch1 >> ch2 && ch1=='{' && ch2=='"')`

Comment: @LokiAstari you are correct. I will check the book, probably the author uses it that way and I didn't notice. (after all, it's in the if (is>>ContactAge>>ch1 && ch1=='}') line)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main difference between `operator >>` and `get()` is that the former skips leading whitespace, while the latter doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Your variant "worked", but imposes stricter requirements on the input.

The original code will succesfully read `{ "John Doe" , 29 }`, but if you use `get` you will also read the whitespace, and fail.

Comment: I noticed I have
    if (is>>ch1 && ch1==',') 
and when I tried "Hector Corea" it was converted to "HectorCorea". after I changed it to 
    is.get(ch1)
it worked like a charm.